# Do abilities have position?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Do abilities have position?

For example, there is an object with elasticity, and the object is on the desk, then elasticity is on the desk?

Comment: Elasticity is a property rather than an "ability", and no, properties, like other universals, are not spatiotemporally located, see [SEP, Properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/). Indeed, they can be many places at once, since there are many elastic objects, and would make sense even if there were none.